# Is the action $T \times G \to G$ Poisson?

Tags: lie-groups, poisson-geometry

Let $G$ be a [Poisson-Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson%E2%80%93Lie_group). Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold.

In [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/dg-ga/9602001.pdf), the third paragraph of page 1238, it is said that an action $G \times M \to M$ is called Poisson if $G \times M \to M$ is a Poisson map.

Let $G=GL_n$, $U$ the subgroup of $GL_n$ consisting of all unipotent upper triangular matrices, and $T$ a maximal torus of $G$. Consider the action
$$
T \times G \to G \\
(t, g) \mapsto tgt^{-1}
$$
Is this action Poisson?

Consider the action
$$
T \times G \to G \\
(t, g) \mapsto tgw(t)^{-1}
$$
where $w \in Aut(T)$. Is this action Poisson?

Consider the action
$$
U \times G \to G \\
(u, g) \mapsto ug
$$
Is this action Poisson?

Consider the action
$$
U \times G \to G \\
(u, g) \mapsto gu^{-1}
$$
Is this action Poisson?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ingredients:

1. The composite of Poisson maps is Poisson
2. The action map $G\times G\to G$ is Poisson
3. Your choice of $T,U$ should be Poisson submanifolds of $G$. You didn't say which Poisson structure you're using so theoretically I can't tell, but I'm sure you're interested in the standard one in which case, they are.

Then the map $T\times G \to G\times G \to G$ is Poisson, likewise for $U$.

What's more interesting is that $T$'s Poisson structure is trivial, but $U$'s isn't, so each $\{t\}\times G\to G$ is an ichthyomorphism, but most $\{u\} \times G \to G$ aren't.

EDIT: I misread the action. See the comment below.

Comment: It seems the question regarding $T$ was about the adjoint action, not the regular action. In particular, the conjugation map $G\times G\rightarrow G$ is not Poisson if you take the Poisson-Lie structure on all factors. If $G$ is factorizable, there's a different Poisson structure (not Poisson-Lie) due to Semenov-Tian-Shansky on $G$ for which the conjugation map becomes Poisson.

Comment: @Pavel Safronov, thank you very much. Is Semenov-Tian-Shansky's paper you mentioned [this paper](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKw_etmdjYAhVBZ1AKHQyeDOAQFghEMAQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ems-ph.org%2FJOURNALS%2Fshow_pdf.php%3Fissn%3D0034-5318%26vol%3D21%26iss%3D6%26rank%3D6&usg=AOvVaw18G8DgZ07Zce4969njYqtf)? In which theorem he proved that the conjugation map $G \times G \to G$ is Poisson with respect to a different Poisson structure?